# Using `itertools.groupby()` to get lists of runs of strings that start with `A`?

Tags: python, python-itertools

The (abstracted) problem is this: I have a log file

```
A: 1
A: 2
A: 3
B: 4
B: 5
A: 6
C: 7
D: 8
A: 9
A: 10
A: 11
```

and I want to end up with a list of lists like this:

```
[["1", "2", "3"], ["6"], ["9", "10", "11"]]
```

where the file has been broken up into "runs" of strings starting with `A`. I know that I can use `itertools.groupby` to solve this, and right now I have this solution (where `f` is a list of the lines in the file).

```
starts_with_a = lambda x: x.startswith("A")
coalesced = [g for _, g in groupby(f), key=starts_with_a]
runs = [re.sub(r'A: ', '', s) for s in coalesced if starts_with_a(s)]
```

So I use groupby, but then I have to filter out the stuff that doesn't start with "A". This is okay, and pretty terse, but is there a more elegant way to do it? I'd love a way that:

- doesn't require two passes
- is terser (and/or) is more readable

Help me harness the might of `itertools`!

Comment: You don't have to use `itertools`. I'll try to write something up.

Comment: I think the abstraction may be too dumbed down, are all the strings one character? do the numbers ascend like that in order 1, 2, ..., N?

Comment: @RyanHaining: Why is it *too* dumbed down? They want to pick out consecutive runs based on a simple test. It then doesn't matter what the test is.

Comment: @MartijnPieters if the numbers actually climb like that then most of the string is irrelevant, you only need look at the first character. I'm also making sure OP is looking for the contents of the line and not the line numbers (which I think they are).

Comment: @RyanHaining: Given the rest of the description I think it is safe to assume the line contents, whatever they are, need to be grouped. Using numbered lines makes this easier to illustrate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, filter out the lines that don't start with `A` but use the *key* produced by `groupby()` for each group returned. It's the return value of the `key` function, so it'll be `True` for those lines that do start with `A`. I'd use `str.partition()` here instead of a regular expression:

```
coalesce = (g for key, g in groupby(f, key=lambda x: x[:1] == "A") if key)
runs = [[res.partition(':')[-1].strip() for res in group] for group in coalesce]
```

Since your `str.startswith()` argument is a fixed-width string literal, you may as well use slicing; `x[:1]` slices of the first character and compares that to `'A'`, which gives you the same test as `x.startswith('A')`.

I used a generator expression to group the `groupby()` filtering; you *could* just inline that into just the one list comprehension:

```
runs = [[res.partition(':')[-1].strip() for res in group]
        for key, group in groupby(f, key=lambda x: x[:1] == "A") if key]
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> f = '''\
... A: 1
... A: 2
... A: 3
... B: 4
... B: 5
... A: 6
... C: 7
... D: 8
... A: 9
... A: 10
... A: 11
... '''.splitlines(True)
>>> coalesce = (g for key, g in groupby(f, key=lambda x: x[:1] == "A") if key)
>>> [[res.partition(':')[-1].strip() for res in group] for group in coalesce]
[['1', '2', '3'], ['6'], ['9', '10', '11']]
```

Comment: Silly question: Why did you go to the trouble of asking `splitlines` to keep the line endings when you `strip` 'em away anyway?

Comment: @ShadowRanger: to demonstrate that line endings are handled correctly. Iterating over a file object would also have the line endings included.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: in other words, using `str.splitlines(True)` closely mimics what a file object would produce when iterating.

Comment: Gotcha. Makes sense, I just forgot we were simulating a file.

Comment: Ah, never thought to use the key. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You want terse? OK, you got it.

```
>>> lst = ['A: 1', 'A: 2', 'A: 3', 'B: 4', 'B: 5', 'A: 6', 'C: 7', 'D: 8', 'A: 9', 'A: 10', 'A: 11']
>>> [[x[1] for x in group[1]] for group in itertools.groupby((line.split(': ') for line in lst), key=lambda a:a[0]) if group[0]=='A']
[['1', '2', '3'], ['6'], ['9', '10', '11']]
```

Breaking it down, from the inside out:

```
(line.split(': ') for line in lst)
```

This is a generator expression that splits each element into its alpha key and the associated string value.

```
for group in itertools.groupby(..., key=lambda a:a[0])
```

This simply groups the elements by the alpha key that was determined in the first step.

```
... if group[0]=='A'
```

This simply excludes any results that don't match the criteria specified in the question. You could also use `if not group[0].startswith('A')` if the string isn't a single character.

```
[x[1] for x in group[1]] for ...]
```

This is a list comprehension that builds a list from the results of `groupby` that match the earlier condition. `groupby` returns an iterator as the second return value (`group[1]`), so we simply turn that iterator into a list with a list comprehension. `x[0]` is the key value, and `x[1]` is the string that follows it.

```
[...]
```

The desired output is a list, so a list comprehension makes it so. The whole operation occurs with a single pass over the input.

Comment: What in the colorful Hell!? I like it. +1

Comment: @AustinKootz I just realized that the `list` calls were redundant. Now even terser.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not so pythonic way in one loop without itertools:

```
lines = '''
A: 1
A: 2
A: 3
B: 4
B: 5
A: 6
C: 7
D: 8
A: 9
A: 10
A: 11
'''

res = []
cont_last = []
for line in lines.splitlines():
    if line.startswith('A: '):
        cont_last.append(line.replace('A: ', ''))
    else:
        if cont_last:
            res.append(cont_last)
        cont_last = []

if cont_last:
    res.append(cont_last)    

print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Without needing itertools, this does the full file with only one iteration:

```
 lines = open('logfile.txt','r').readlines()

 out_list = []
 temp_list = []

 for line in lines:

     if line.split(':')[0].strip() == 'A':
          temp_list.append(line.split(':')[1].strip())

     elif temp_list:
          out_list.append(temp_list)
          temp_list = []

 if temp_list:
     out_list.append(temp_list)
     temp_list = []

 print (out_list)
```

I know you asked for `itertools` I just don't have it handy, so I couldn't have debugged it. Hope this helps.

Comment: `itertools.groupby()` uses just the one iteration too.

Comment: What are `i_0` and `i_1` used for? And why reset the `temp_list` variable when the `for` loop is done?

Comment: And last but not least, why call `readlines()` when you could just iterate directly over the file object? That way you don't read *all* lines into memory in one go.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I swear, if I could remove `.readlines()` from the file object interfaces, I would. Because it exists with an obvious name, everyone seems to find it and use it, never bothering to notice that direct iteration is better in every way (and if you really need a `list`, you just wrap the file object in the `list` constructor, which is more succinct and general anyway).

Comment: @ShadowRanger: I'm quite surprised it made it into Python 3, to be honest. `list(fileobject)` gives you the same result, so why keep `fileobject.readlines()`? `range()` was replaced by `xrange()` with the same motivation after all.

Comment: @AustinKootz: Hmm, what version of Python are you using that doesn't come with `itertools`?

Comment: Government project, many libraries are deliberately missing from our dev environment to avoid namespace conflicts with some custom libraries.